# IBM Worklight - How to send push notification from SharePoint server

Tags: android, sharepoint, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented push notifications and am able to send text from command prompt by invoking the pushbackendemulator .jar file, but the question now is how to send notification text from a Sharepoint server? Do we need to place the backend .jar file to sharepoint server? or is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: Is this question is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The PushBackendEmulator.jar file is meant only for simulation purposes in the IBM Worklight Getting Started push notifications sample application (because there is no actual "push server" available).

When moving to a production environment, you should use the [adapter invocation service](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_adapter_invocation_service.html). You use your service to invoke the adapter procedure and send the push notification.

You can also [use `polling` instead of `pushing` (page 23)](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf).

As for how to implement this on the Sharepoint side, there are all sort of guides on the web. This is outside the Worklight scope.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163784.aspx
- http://kniganapolke.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/call-sharepoint-web-service-from-a-php-script/
- ...